# How to change the layout of a ggraph network plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, networking, ggraph

I'm working on a report needs to plot a network using the ggraph package in r.
My code is:

```
net <- graph_from_data_frame(d=edges,vertices=nodes,directed = F)
ggraph(net) + 
geom_edge_link(aes(alpha=color)) + 
geom_node_point(aes(shape=as.factor(gender),alpha=location))
```

and I get a [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uABk3.png):, looks like a mushroom :D, is there any way can change the network to another shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the layout, e.g. `ggraph(net, layout = 'kk')`.

Answer (score 2):

`ggraph` has several built in layouts which you can see in this help page: `?create_layout`.

It also pulls in several layout algorithms from `igraph` which you can browse in the appropriate help page: `?layout_tbl_graph_igraph`.

In either case, you can specify them in either the `ggraph` function:

```r
ggraph(net, layout = "fr")
```

Or use the `create_layout` function:

```r
create_layout(net, layout = "drl")
```